# Detecting keyboard input

Tags: java, shell, javafx

I want to use JavaFX as a solution to Java's [issues with buffered input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-an-user-input-to-close) making things like 'press any key to continue' not easy.

I plan to use an event listener to detect keyboard input. But before I start down that road I want to know if this is on the right track.

Is the code below a good way to use JavaFX to implement a shell-based program?

- Is this the minimum JavaFX code required to do shell?
- Am I missing something that's gonna bite me down the road (like some kind of object de-referencing: I am very new to JavaFX so I don't have a clue!)
- Is it OK to consider the `start` method as effectively now my `main` method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextBased extends Application {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Application.launch(argv);
    }   

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.nextLine();
    Platform.exit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: JavaFX is mainly used with a GUI. You are simply overcomplicating your problem. The rest is the same as plain old Java. No de-referencing unless you do it manually; the GC is very smart about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a lot to review here, the only thing that's jumping at me is that this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
>     System.out.println("Hello world");
>     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
>     scanner.nextLine();
>     Platform.exit();
>     }
> ```

Should be indented like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.nextLine();
    Platform.exit();
}
```

---

> *Is this the minimum JavaFX code required to do shell?*

Well technically printing "Hello world" and waiting for the ENTER key is not needed if what you want is the *minimum* code. But then, what would your program be *doing* :-)

> *Am I missing something that's gonna bite me down the road (like some kind of object de-referencing: I am very new to JavaFX so I don't have a clue!)*

I know nothing of JavaFX, but if garbage collection is anywhere like .net, you have nothing to worry about because AFAICT you're not creating any object that's holding on to a reference that would prevent its garbage collection.

> *Is it OK to consider the start method as effectively now my main method?*

Probably. But it's not immediately clear what happens to `argv`.